# How to avoid additional vertical space using multicol in ModernCV's cvitem?

Tags: vertical-alignment, itemize, moderncv

In a `moderncv` document, I'd like to list within a `cvitem` several `item`s in two columns (preferably using `multicol`).

However, this messes up the vertical alignment of the `cvitem` - the title to the left is shifted upward or downward (if a `minipage` is used):

[image: image of MWE]

**What's the right way to set up two columns of `item`s in `moderncv`'s `cvitem`, so that it's not vertically shifted?**

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}

\firstname{First}
\familyname{Last}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\cvitem{default}{
\begin{itemize}
    \item default itemize without multicols
    \item second item 
\end{itemize}}

\cvitem{multicols}{
    \begin{multicols}{2} 
        \begin{itemize} 
            \item item 1 
            \item item 2 
            \item item 3 
            \item item 4 
        \end{itemize}
    \end{multicols}}

\cvitem{minipage}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \begin{multicols}{2}
                \item Item a
                \item Item b
                \item Item c
                \item Item d
            \end{multicols}
        \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case the issue comes with environment `multicols`, it simply adds some blank space you do not want.

I didn't investigate where that blank space comes from excactly, but you can use the following work around:

```
    \vspace{-10pt}% <===================================================
%   \vspace{-0.8\baselineskip}% <=======================================
```

Add one of the commands shown above, I used the first one in the following complete mwe. Add this command before you start environment `multicols`.

With the following compete MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}

\firstname{First}
\familyname{Last}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\cvitem{default}{
\begin{itemize}
    \item default itemize without multicols
    \item second item 
\end{itemize}}

\cvitem{multicols}{
    \vspace{-10pt}% <===================================================
%   \vspace{-0.8\baselineskip}% <=======================================
    \begin{multicols}{2} 
        \begin{itemize} 
            \item item 1 
            \item item 2 
            \item item 3 
            \item item 4 
        \end{itemize}
    \end{multicols}}

\cvitem{minipage}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \begin{multicols}{2}
                \item Item a
                \item Item b
                \item Item c
                \item Item d
            \end{multicols}
        \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image]

Play with the used values to fit your needs ...